# Retrieving item text from Win32 ListView using JNA, C# is fine, but java can't get text

Tags: java, c#, jna

I want to retrieve item information (text would be enough) from a Win32 ListView control (SysListView32). I'm using JNA's sendMessage() to send LVM_GETITEMTEXT. SendMessage() takes a pointer to a LVITEM structure which looks like this: [LVITEM structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx):

In c#, I successfully get the text from ListItem,

```
    int hwnd;   //窗口句柄
    int process;//进程句柄
    int pointer;
    int pointer2;
    private const uint LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const uint LVM_GETITEMCOUNT = LVM_FIRST + 4;//获取列表行数
    private const uint LVM_GETHEADER = LVM_FIRST + 31;
    private const uint LVM_GETITEMTEXT = LVM_FIRST + 45;//获取列表内的内容
    private const uint LVM_GETITEMW = LVM_FIRST + 75;

    private const uint HDM_GETITEMCOUNT = 0x1200;//获取列表列数

    private const uint PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;//允许函数VirtualProtectEx使用此句柄修改进程的虚拟内存
    private const uint PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;//允许函数访问权限
    private const uint PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;//允许函数写入权限

    private const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;//为特定的页面区域分配内存中或磁盘的页面文件中的物理存储
    private const uint MEM_RELEASE = 0x8000;
    private const uint MEM_RESERVE = 0x2000;//保留进程的虚拟地址空间,而不分配任何物理存储

    private const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 4;

    private int LVIF_TEXT = 0x0001;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]//查找窗口
    private static extern int FindWindow(
                                        string strClassName,    //窗口类名
                                        string strWindowName    //窗口标题
    );

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]//在窗口列表中寻找与指定条件相符的第一个子窗口
    private static extern int FindWindowEx(
                                          int hwndParent, // handle to parent window
                                        int hwndChildAfter, // handle to child window
                                          string className, //窗口类名            
                                          string windowName // 窗口标题
    );
    [DllImport("user32.DLL")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]//找出某个窗口的创建者(线程或进程),返回创建者的标志符
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hwnd, out int processId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]//打开一个已存在的进程对象,并返回进程的句柄
    private static extern int OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]//为指定的进程分配内存地址:成功则返回分配内存的首地址
    private static extern int VirtualAllocEx(int hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]//从指定内存中读取字节集数据
    private static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
                                        int hProcess, //被读取者的进程句柄
                                        int lpBaseAddress,//开始读取的内存地址
                                        IntPtr lpBuffer, //数据存储变量
                                        int nSize, //要写入多少字节
                                        ref uint vNumberOfBytesRead//读取长度
    );
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]//将数据写入内存中
    private static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
                                        int hProcess,//由OpenProcess返回的进程句柄
                                        int lpBaseAddress, //要写的内存首地址,再写入之前,此函数将先检查目标地址是否可用,并能容纳待写入的数据
                                        IntPtr lpBuffer, //指向要写的数据的指针
                                        int nSize, //要写入的字节数
                                        ref uint vNumberOfBytesRead
    );
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(int handle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]//在其它进程中释放申请的虚拟内存空间
    private static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(
                                int hProcess,//目标进程的句柄,该句柄必须拥有PROCESS_VM_OPERATION的权限
                                int lpAddress,//指向要释放的虚拟内存空间首地址的指针
                                uint dwSize,
                                uint dwFreeType//释放类型
    );
    /// <summary>
    /// LVITEM结构体,是列表视图控件的一个重要的数据结构
    /// 占空间：4(int)x7=28个byte
    /// </summary>
    private struct LVITEM  //结构体
    {
        //public int a;
        public int mask;//说明此结构中哪些成员是有效的
        public int iItem;//项目的索引值(可以视为行号)从0开始
        public int iSubItem; //子项的索引值(可以视为列号)从0开始
        public int state;//子项的状态
        public int stateMask; //状态有效的屏蔽位
        public IntPtr pszText;  //主项或子项的名称
        public int cchTextMax;//pszText所指向的缓冲区大小
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>  
    /// LV列表总行数
    /// </summary>
    private int ListView_GetItemRows(int handle)
    {
        return SendMessage(handle, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
    }
    /// <summary>  
    /// LV列表总列数
    /// </summary>
    private int ListView_GetItemCols(int handle)
    {
        return SendMessage(handle, HDM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int headerhwnd; //listview控件的列头句柄
        int rows, cols;  //listview控件中的行列数
        int processId; //进程pid  

        hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "Windows 任务管理器");
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "#32770", null);
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "SysListView32", null);//进程界面窗口的句柄,通过SPY获取
        headerhwnd = SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);//listview的列头句柄

        rows = ListView_GetItemRows(hwnd);//总行数，即进程的数量
        cols = ListView_GetItemCols(headerhwnd);//列表列数
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out processId);

        //打开并插入进程
        process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, false, processId);
        //申请代码的内存区,返回申请到的虚拟内存首地址
        pointer = VirtualAllocEx(process, IntPtr.Zero, 4096, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
        pointer2 = VirtualAllocEx(process, IntPtr.Zero, 4096, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
        string[,] tempStr;//二维数组
        string[] temp = new string[cols];

        tempStr = GetListViewItmeValue(rows, cols);//将要读取的其他程序中的ListView控件中的文本内容保存到二维数组中

        listView1.Items.Clear();//清空LV控件信息
        //输出数组中保存的其他程序的LV控件信息
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                temp[j] = tempStr[i, j];
            }
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(temp);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 从内存中读取指定的LV控件的文本内容
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rows">要读取的LV控件的行数</param>
    /// <param name="cols">要读取的LV控件的列数</param>
    /// <returns>取得的LV控件信息</returns>
    private string[,] GetListViewItmeValue(int rows, int cols)
    {
        string[,] tempStr = new string[rows, cols];//二维数组:保存LV控件的文本信息
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                int size = 40;// Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LVITEM));
                byte[] vBuffer = new byte[256];//定义一个临时缓冲区
                LVITEM[] vItem = new LVITEM[1];
                vItem[0].mask = LVIF_TEXT;//说明pszText是有效的
               // vItem[0].iItem = i;     //行号
               // vItem[0].iSubItem = j;  //列号
                vItem[0].cchTextMax = vBuffer.Length;//所能存储的最大的文本为256字节
                vItem[0].pszText = (IntPtr)pointer2;// ((int)pointer + size);
                uint vNumberOfBytesRead = 0;

                //把数据写到vItem中
                //pointer为申请到的内存的首地址
                //UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement:获取指定数组中指定索引处的元素的地址

                IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(vItem, 0);
                WriteProcessMemory(process, pointer, intPtr, size, ref vNumberOfBytesRead);

                //发送LVM_GETITEMW消息给hwnd,将返回的结果写入pointer指向的内存空间
                SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_GETITEMW, i, pointer);

                //从pointer指向的内存地址开始读取数据,写入缓冲区vBuffer中
               // ReadProcessMemory(process, ((int)pointer + size), Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(vBuffer, 0), vBuffer.Length, ref vNumberOfBytesRead);
                ReadProcessMemory(process, pointer2, Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(vBuffer, 0), vBuffer.Length, ref vNumberOfBytesRead);

                string vText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(vBuffer, 0, (int)vNumberOfBytesRead); ;
                tempStr[i, j] = vText;
            }
        }
        VirtualFreeEx(process, pointer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);//在其它进程中释放申请的虚拟内存空间,MEM_RELEASE方式很彻底,完全回收
        CloseHandle(process);//关闭打开的进程对象
        return tempStr;
    }
```

I use jna to rewrite in Java, but i can't get the text, vText always is '', if someone can tell me what's wrong in my java code?

The editor can't submit full java code, so , I submit the java code into the github, the code is [here](https://github.com/rapidark/synthuse-src/blob/master/src/test2/WindowsMonitor.java).

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    HWND hwnd = User32Ex.instance.FindWindow("#32770", "Windows 任务管理器");
    hwnd = User32Ex.instance.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "#32770", null);
    hwnd = User32Ex.instance.FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "SysListView32", null);HWND listViewHwnd = hwnd;
    System.out.println(listViewHwnd);

    PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
    User32Ex.instance.GetWindowThreadProcessId(listViewHwnd, pointer);
    int pid = pointer.getPointer().getInt(0);
    Pointer process = Kernel32Ex.instance.OpenProcess(Api.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | Api.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, false, new Pointer(pid));
    IntByReference addr = new IntByReference(0);
    SIZE_T size = new SIZE_T(4096);
    IntByReference epLvi = Kernel32Ex.instance.VirtualAllocEx(new HANDLE(process), addr, size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    LVITEM_VISTA lvitem = new LVITEM_VISTA();
    lvitem.mask = 1;
    lvitem.cchTextMax = 256;
    lvitem.pszText = new Memory(256);

    IntByReference bytesWritten = new IntByReference();
    Api.Kernel32Ex.instance.WriteProcessMemory(new HANDLE(process), epLvi, lvitem.getPointer(), lvitem.size(),bytesWritten);
    LRESULT isSuccess = Api.User32Ex.instance.SendMessage(listViewHwnd, 4171, new WPARAM(0), lvitem);
    System.out.println("isSuccess:" + isSuccess);


    byte[] result = new byte[256];
    ByteBuffer bufDest = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(256);

    Pointer ptrSrc = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(bufDest);

    Api.Kernel32Ex.instance.ReadProcessMemory(new HANDLE(process), lvitem.pszText, ptrSrc, 256,bytesWritten);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bufDest.array()));
    Api.Kernel32Ex.instance.VirtualFreeEx(new HANDLE(process), epLvi, new SIZE_T(4096), new DWORD(MEM_DECOMMIT | MEM_RELEASE));
    Api.Kernel32Ex.instance.CloseHandle(new HANDLE(process));
}
```

LVITEM_VISTA define

```
public static class LVITEM_VISTA extends Structure {
        public int mask;
        public int iItem; 
        public int iSubItem; 
        public int state; 
        public int stateMask; 
        public Pointer pszText;
        public int cchTextMax; 
        public int iImage; 
        public LPARAM lParam; 
        public int iIndent; 
        public int iGoupId; 
        public int cColumns; 
        public Pointer puColumns; 
        //NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA
        public Pointer piColFmt;
        public int iGroup;
        @Override
        protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[] { 
"mask",  "iItem",  "iSubItem",  "state", "stateMask", "pszText", "cchTextMax",  "iImage", "lParam",  "iIndent", "iGoupId",  "cColumns", "puColumns", "piColFmt", "iGroup" });
        }
    }
```